# What is the best SQL join to join two SELECT output?

Tags: sql

I have a first SQL query which return the following :

| TEST_NAME | SUBNAME | BDATE | CODE | Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TEST1 | Blabla1 | 01-JAN-2022 | TEST_A | 15645 |
| TEST1 | Blabla1 | 01-MAR-2022 | TEST_B | 58464 |
| TEST1 | Blabla1 | 01-JUN-2022 | TEST_C | 46456 |
| TEST1 | Blabla1 | 01-SEP-2022 | TEST_D | 68676 |
| TEST1 | Blabla1 | 01-DEC-2022 | TEST_E | 68766 |
| TEST2 | Blabla2 | 01-JAN-2022 | TEST_A | 15645 |
| TEST2 | Blabla2 | 01-MAR-2022 | TEST_B | 58464 |
| TEST2 | Blabla2 | 01-JUN-2022 | TEST_C | 46456 |
| TEST2 | Blabla2 | 01-SEP-2022 | TEST_D | 68676 |
| TEST2 | Blabla2 | 01-DEC-2022 | TEST_E | 68766 |

On an other side I have made an other sql request :

```
SELECT * 
FROM db.Test_Table TT
WHERE TT.TC_CODE = 1
```

Which gibes the below output :

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TEST1 | 05-MAR-2022 | 4564123 |
| TEST1 | 05-DEC-2022 | 1561618 |
| TEST2 | 05-JAN-2022 | 1651156 |
| TEST2 | 05-JUN-2022 | 1564132 |
| TEST2 | 05-SEP-2022 | 1561565 |

I was wondering how to simply join the above table to the first one, to have the below output :

| TEST_NAME | SUBNAME | BDATE | CODE | Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TEST1 | Blabla1 | 01-JAN-2022 | TEST_A | 15645 |
| TEST1 | Blabla1 | 01-MAR-2022 | TEST_B | 58464 |
| TEST1 | Blabla1 | 05-MAR-2022 | NewItem | 4564123 |
| TEST1 | Blabla1 | 01-JUN-2022 | TEST_C | 46456 |
| TEST1 | Blabla1 | 01-SEP-2022 | TEST_D | 68676 |
| TEST1 | Blabla1 | 01-DEC-2022 | TEST_E | 68766 |
| TEST1 | Blabla1 | 05-DEC-2022 | NewItem | 1561618 |
| TEST2 | Blabla2 | 01-JAN-2022 | TEST_A | 15645 |
| TEST2 | Blabla2 | 05-JAN-2022 | NewItem | 1651156 |
| TEST2 | Blabla2 | 01-MAR-2022 | TEST_B | 58464 |
| TEST2 | Blabla2 | 01-JUN-2022 | TEST_C | 46456 |
| TEST2 | Blabla2 | 05-JUN-2022 | NewItem | 1564132 |
| TEST2 | Blabla2 | 01-SEP-2022 | TEST_D | 68676 |
| TEST2 | Blabla2 | 05-SEP-2022 | NewItem | 1561565 |
| TEST2 | Blabla2 | 01-DEC-2022 | TEST_E | 68766 |

TRYING to do :

```
SELECT * FROM T1
UNION
SELECT 
TT.A as TEST_NAME,
TT.B as BDATE,
TT.C as Number,
FROM db.Test_Table TT
```

Throw :

```
01789. 00000 -  "query block has incorrect number of result columns"
```

Also I don't know how to fill empty cells with corresponding value, I guess that if the `UNION` works, I would have the following DF

| TEST_NAME | SUBNAME | BDATE | CODE | Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TEST1 | Blabla1 | 01-JAN-2022 | TEST_A | 15645 |
| TEST1 | Blabla1 | 01-MAR-2022 | TEST_B | 58464 |
| TEST1 | (null) | 05-MAR-2022 | NewItem | 4564123 |
| TEST1 | Blabla1 | 01-JUN-2022 | TEST_C | 46456 |
| TEST1 | Blabla1 | 01-SEP-2022 | TEST_D | 68676 |
| TEST1 | Blabla1 | 01-DEC-2022 | TEST_E | 68766 |
| TEST1 | (null) | 05-DEC-2022 | NewItem | 1561618 |
| TEST2 | Blabla2 | 01-JAN-2022 | TEST_A | 15645 |
| TEST2 | (null) | 05-JAN-2022 | NewItem | 1651156 |
| TEST2 | Blabla2 | 01-MAR-2022 | TEST_B | 58464 |
| TEST2 | Blabla2 | 01-JUN-2022 | TEST_C | 46456 |
| TEST2 | (null) | 05-JUN-2022 | NewItem | 1564132 |
| TEST2 | Blabla2 | 01-SEP-2022 | TEST_D | 68676 |
| TEST2 | (null) | 05-SEP-2022 | NewItem | 1561565 |
| TEST2 | Blabla2 | 01-DEC-2022 | TEST_E | 68766 |

How can I replace these (null) by right value ? For this example values would be `Blabla1` or `Blabla2` depending on `TEST_NAME`

Comment: SELECT ... FROM t1 UNION SELECT ... from t2 ORDER BY 'TEST_NAME', 'BDATE'?

Comment: Use `UNION` to combine the output, in the second query just select `'NewItem' as Code`

Comment: 1. Check the difference between `UNION` answered in the above comments and `UNION ALL`. 2. If you want to sort the output as hinted in your question, you will need to use a sub-query; `SELECT * FROM (SELECT ... FROM T1 UNION ALL SELECT ... FROM T2) T ORDER BY ...`

Comment: @GrzegorzSapijaszko I think `UNION` works only if I have the same number of column and the same columns in both table ? I've edited my post so you can see a much more realistic idea of what I try to do.

Comment: @Atmo I think `UNION` or `UNION ALL` works only if I have the same number of column and the same columns in both table ? I've edited my post so you can see a much more realistic idea of what I try to do.

Comment: @NikitaChayka not sure if I can use `Union` if both table don't have the same column name & number of columns.

Comment: That's why you need to add `as` to do the same names (aliases) and you need to add 'NewItem' as code to match the number of columns

Comment: @NikitaChayka Thank you but what would it be for `SUBNAME` ? How can SQL do to fill empty cells with value store by the the first table ? `Blabla1`, `Blabla2` ect..

Comment: @NikitaChayka I've made an edit.

Comment: Simply `SELECT TEST_NAME, TEST_SUBNAME, ... FROM T1 UNION ALL SELECT TEST_NAME, NULL, ..., 'NewItem', ... FROM T2` and there you go, `TEST_SUBNAME` from `T1` is supplemented by an empty column from `T2` and `CODE` is supplemented by the constant `'NewItem'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: we start with a `UNION ALL` to combine the 2 tables.

```
       SELECT TEST_NAME, SUBNAME, BDATE, CODE     , Number FROM T1
UNION  SELECT A        , NULL   , B    , 'NewItem', C      FROM db.Test_Table
```

BTW, the column names are entirely deduced from the query before the first `UNION`, you can remove all the `AS ColumnAlias` after that first part.

---

Step 2: with the above query, the `SUBNAME` column is empty for all the records that come from `Test_Table`.

On that part, you must notice your database is not super good in terms of normal forms ([1NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), [2NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form), [3NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form)). Here, it means I will need to use the `DISTINCT` keyword, which should normally not be necessary.

There are 2 methods to fill `SUBNAME`

**Method 1**: Scalar subquery (= a query that returns a single value).

Replace `NULL` from the query in Step 1 by:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT SUBNAME FROM T1 WHERE TEST_NAME = Test_Table.A)
```

**Method 2**: JOIN

```
...
UNION ALL
SELECT A, T.SUBNAME, B, 'NewItem', C
FROM db.Test_Table
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT TEST_NAME, SUBNAME FROM T1) T ON A = TEST_NAME
```

Again, I suppose you will not need `DISTINCT in your real case`.

Additional notes:

- Method 1 will throw an error if the subquery returns more than 1 record (= if a `TEST_NAME` is linked to 2 `SUBNAME`)
  If you expect `TEST_NAME` will only be linked to 1 value for `SUBNAME`, then I urge you to consider this error as a good thing, that is a protection that will tell you the data may not look like what you expect.
- In Oracle but possibly in some other databases, a scalar subquery could be faster than the `JOIN` counterpart due to the use of a cache. See [here](https://hourim.wordpress.com/2019/12/18/scalar-subquery-caching-the-select-from-dual-trick/) for instance.

Comment: It does give me the last table : 

I have NULL for each subname from df.Test_Table and not `Blabla1` or `Blabla2`. Am I missing something ?

Comment: Ohh my bad, I had not seen your last edit.

Comment: No worries, Hope you do have an Idea of how to do this :/

Comment: @TourEiffel, I have added some notes to my answer, as I felt I rushed it a bit... Try to have a look to them, it could be important.

Comment: thank you very much it is reall helpfull. Last point is that If I want to use the scalar subquery I need to save my first request as a kind of variable : 

`Set @Variable = (SELECT * FROM ...)`

So then I can do :

`(SELECT DISTINCT SUBNAME FROM @Variable WHERE TEST_NAME = Test_Table.A)`. 

Is it the best way to do ?

Comment: IMO, the best way is to literally replace the `NULL` keyword from step 1 by the scalar subquery (resulting in `SELECT (SELECT ... FROM ...), ... FROM ...`). This does not look like so complicated a query you could not execute it in 1 go.